# Which exceptions/errors can we mark as fatal in firebase for flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, crashlytics

I am working on a flutter project where I've integrated firebase. I need to report crashes to firebase crashlytics. In flutter however app doesn't exist on crash, screen blacks out disabling functionality.
There is a FlutterError handler,
Which catches uncaught exceptions in flutter code.
But in most cases it also catches non serious exceptions like api failures.
I am using a conditional marking of errors and exceptions as fatal/non fatal.
Currently i have marked StateError,FormatException,ConcurrentModificationError, and OutOfMemoryError as fatal and rest will be non fatal by default.
Is there any general guideline on which error should be marked as fatal.
Which more items can i add to this list to mark as fatal?